# Using Flask with apscheduler

Tags: python, flask

I using Python Flask to along with apscheduler and trying to add/remove jobs as follows:

```
sched = Scheduler()
sched.start()
print "Schedular Started"


def new_job():
    @sched.interval_schedule(seconds=2)
    def job_function():
        print "Hello World"


@app.route('/add')
def add():
    new_job()
    return 'started'
```

This bit works as expected. However, when I try to remove the job, like shown here:

```
@app.route('/remove')
def remove():
    sched.unschedule_job(job_function.job)
    return "Removed"
```

I'm getting a

> NameError: global name 'job_function' is not defined" as expected.

My question is how can I remove a job using a different route?

Regards.

Answer (score 7):

OK Sorted it!

For anybody else that needs to do this:

```
@sched.interval_schedule(seconds=2)
def job_function():
    print "Hello World"
```

Then:

```
sched.unschedule_job(job_function.job)
```